# spring boot application is not supporting externalisation of log4j.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging, log4j

I have spring boot application deployed on IBM Websphere and it's an expanded war file.

Now i don't want my log4j.properties to be processed as part of war file. it should be externalised.

To do that i follow below steps but it is not creating any log file at the defined location.

application.properties:-

```
logging.config=/XX/YY/app_config/XX_cluster_config/YY_config/log4j.properties
```

contents of log4j.properties:-

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, rollingfile
log4j.logger.XX=info
log4j.logger.YY=debug
log4j.logger.XX=error
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
# Pattern to output - note that outputting the caller's location is extremely slow
# See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/docs/api/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p [%t] %m%n %d{ISO8601} %c %n%n

log4j.appender.rollingfile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingfile.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.rollingfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.xml.XMLLayout
log4j.appender.rollingfile.file=/XX/YY/app_logs/spring-XX/default.YY.log.xml

log4j.appender.chainsaw=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.chainsaw.RemoteHost=127.0.0.2
log4j.appender.chainsaw.Port=4485
log4j.appender.chainsaw.LocationInfo=true
```

Somehow it is not creating the default.YY.log.xml at /XX/YY/app_logs/spring-XX/default.YY.log.xml.

if i just replace the same log4j.properties inside war then it is working but i dont want to do that.

I would like to have logging independent from war/jar.

Any help would be appreciated on this.

Comment: Have you tried to specify the location of your `log4j.properties` while executing your WAR file such as `java -war -logging.config=/XX/YY/app_config/XX_cluster_config/YY_config/log4j.properties YOUR_WAR_NAME.war`?

Comment: yes i tried that but it is not working.